# Can not run SBCL-Common-Lisp SB-EXT:RUN-PROGRAM in Ubuntu

Tags: shell, command-line, common-lisp, csh, sbcl

I noticed this problem when i tried to run a function in a program which obviously runs something in the shell and i got this error:

```
Couldn't execute "/bin/csh": No such file or directory
   [Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY] Retry SLIME interactive evaluation request.
 1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 2: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD "worker" RUNNING {10062173C3}>)

Backtrace:
  0: (SB-EXT:RUN-PROGRAM "/bin/csh" ("-fc" "timidity tst.midi") :ENV NIL :ENVIRONMENT NIL :WAIT NIL :SEARCH NIL :PTY NIL :INPUT NIL :IF-INPUT-DOES-NOT-EXIST NIL :OUTPUT NIL :IF-OUTPUT-EXISTS :ERROR :ERROR ..
```

and so on ...

I then tried to run the `SB-EXT:RUN-PROGRAM` function directly and got again the following error:

```
(SB-EXT:RUN-PROGRAM "ls" (list "-l"))

Couldn't execute "ls": No such file or directory
   [Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR]
```

Does anyone know what the problem is and how sbcl finds the commands he needs?

Comment: The `:SEARCH` argument to `SB-EXT:RUN-PROGRAM` decides whether to search `$PATH` for the program. However, the first case uses an absolute pathname, so I would guess that your system either doesn't have `csh`, or it's in a different location.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely since the program tries to run a shell you don't have installed instead of `/bin/sh` which is a POSIX requirement. The best fix is to update the code to use `/bin/sh` instead, but if you have root on your ubuntu-box you can install it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install tcsh
```

This installs a slightly better shell that is compatible with csh. After installing `/bin/csh` exists. To find out what your program does you can run `man csh`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also switch using zsh or bash instead. it worked for me with SBCL running on Ubuntu:

```
(SB-EXT:RUN-PROGRAM "ls" (list "-l") 
             :search "/usr/bin/zsh" 
             :output *standard-output*)
```

Comment: zsh: The unicorn amongst the shells.. Better to stick with posix `/bin/sh`.